# What is the difference between phyletic and phenotypic gradualism?

Tags: evolution

As I understand it, Phenotypic gradualism describes the development of new traits as a series of incremental steps.  How is Phyletic gradualism different?

Comment: By "phenotypic gradualism", did you mean "phyletic gradualism"?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that by "phenotypic gradualism", you actually meant "phyletic gradualism".

Phyletic simply refers to evolution of a lineage. It is relatively rarely used term. phyletic gradualism comes in opposition to punctuated equilibrium. Punctuated equilibrium is the notion that a lot of evolutionary change in a lineage takes place over short periods of time interspaced by period of time where very little evolutionary change happen. Gradualism is the notion that evolutionary changes happen very uniformly over time. For more information have a look at [evo101 > More on punctuated equilibrium](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/side_0_0/punctuated_01)

Comment: Actually my text, Zoology by Hickman, Robertson et al, differentiates between Phenotypic gradualism and Phyletic gradualism, hence my question.

Comment: Can you please give a direct quote that talks about the difference between these two concepts. That might help